# How to get dynamic url from file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a code of php:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$sContent = file_get_contents('http://iztv.com.tr/yayinakisiGunler.aspx?id=1');

$DOM = str_get_html($sContent);   

foreach($DOM -> find('table tr') as $tr)
{
    $saat = $tr -> find('td', 0)->innertext;
    $program = $tr -> find('td', 1)->innertext;
    $rating = $tr -> find('td', 2) -> find('img', 0);
    if($rating)
    {
        $rating = $tr -> find('td', 2) -> find('img', 0) -> src;
    }
    $yayintipi = $tr -> find('td', 2) -> find('img', 1);
    if($yayintipi)
    {
       $yayintipi = $tr -> find('td', 2) -> find('img', 1)->src;
    }
    $detay = $tr -> find('td', 3) -> find('a', 0);
    if($detay)
    {
        $detay = $tr -> find('td', 3) -> find('a', 0) -> href;
    }

    $arr['saat'] = $saat;
    $arr['program adi'] = $program;
    $arr['rating'] = $rating;
    $arr['yayin tipi'] = $yayintipi;
    $arr['detay'] = $detay;
    $arr2[]=$arr;
}
echo json_encode($arr2, true);
?>
```

When I write the path of php file in browser, it returns proper JSON like I wanted. There is no problem in here. But I want to use whatever link I want like  these: "http://iztv.com.tr/yayinakisiGunler.aspx?id=2" or "http://iztv.com.tr/yayinakisiGunler.aspx?id=3" or other links etc.

How can I do that without changing the code and just writing an URL/path to browser?

Comment: Well without changing the code you cannot get the code to do something different. So the actual answer is _No you cannot_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your script using a parameter i.e.

```
example.com/myscript.php?id=2
```

You can use the parameter called `id` in the script to control the parameter used on the site you get contents from.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

if ( ! empty($_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

} else {
    // got no parameter ERROR

    // or got no parameter assume 1
    $id = 1;
}

 $sContent = file_get_contents('http://iztv.com.tr/yayinakisiGunler.aspx?id=' . $id);
```

Of course you should sanitize the $_GET['id'] parameter before you actually use it, but I have left that for you to do.